# Can Sharepoint Content Type be based on document schema

Tags: xml, sharepoint, infopath

I am attempting to use a single Document Library to store and display multiple Xml documents based on a handful of different schemas.  Each schema will have an InfoPath form associated with it.

Can I associate the same file type (.xml) with multiple Content Types, given this will require Sharepoint to inspect the content of the file to determine the matching schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content type is not related from file type in sharepoint. Also sharepoint can't detect content type based on the file content. However it can use document properties to set metadata including content type. Unfortunately xml document doesn't have those so the only way is to  implement custom Feature.